# Discordance between plot and function domain

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

In version 13 on Windows 10

```
Plot[ArcSin[(x^2 - 8)/8] - 2*ArcSin[x/4] + Pi/2, {x, -6, 6}, 
PlotTheme -> "ThickLines", PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 30, WorkingPrecision -> 15]
```

[image]

, but

```
FunctionDomain[ArcSin[(x^2 - 8)/8] - 2*ArcSin[x/4] + Pi/2, x]
```

> `-4 <= x <= 4`

I understand that, for example,  `ArcSin[(x^2 - 8)/8] - 2*ArcSin[x/4] + Pi/2 /. x -> 5` cancels two imaginary parts.

How to explain this bug in `Plot`? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Also `Reduce[ArcSin[(x^2 - 8)/8] == 2*ArcSin[x/4] - Pi/2, x, Reals]` performs `0 <= x <= 4`.

Comment: Does that bug  appear in version 8?

Comment: For some reason `Plot[(ArcSin[(x^2 - 8)/8] - 2*ArcSin[x/4] + Pi/2)*
  Evaluate[Boole[
    FunctionDomain[ArcSin[(x^2 - 8)/8] - 2*ArcSin[x/4] + Pi/2, 
     x]]], {x, -6, 6}, PlotTheme -> "ThickLines", PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotPoints -> 30, WorkingPrecision -> 15]` performs an empty plot.

Comment: You put the `Evaluate` at the wrong level. `Plot[Evaluate[(ArcSin[(x^2 - 8)/8] - 2*ArcSin[x/4] + Pi/2)*Boole[FunctionDomain[ArcSin[(x^2 - 8)/8] - 2*ArcSin[x/4] + Pi/2, x]]], {x, -6, 6}, PlotTheme -> "ThickLines", PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 30, WorkingPrecision -> 15]`

Comment: Thank you, but this is not a workaround since the multiplication by `Boole[FunctionDomain[ArcSin[(x^2 - 8)/8] - 2*ArcSin[x/4] + Pi/2, x]]]` changes nothing for `x>4`.

Comment: I was responding to your observation that your plot was empty. `Boole` evaluates to zero when its argument is `False`, so you should expect `zero`. If you are looking for a workaround, presumably you want `ConditionalExpression`, i.e., `Plot[Evaluate[ConditionalExpression[(ArcSin[(x^2 - 8)/8] - 2*ArcSin[x/4] + Pi/2), FunctionDomain[ArcSin[(x^2 - 8)/8] - 2*ArcSin[x/4] + Pi/2, x]]], {x, -6, 6}, PlotTheme -> "ThickLines", PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 30, WorkingPrecision -> 15]`

Comment: Just to compare. The command of Maple 2022 `plot(arcsin((x^2 - 8)/8) - 2*arcsin(x/4) + Pi/2, x = -6 .. 6)` draws the plot only on the interval $[-4,4]$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

ReImPlot[{ArcSin[(x^2 - 8)/8], 2 ArcSin[x/4] - Pi/2},
 {x, -6, 6},
 PlotStyle ->
  {Directive[Blue, Thick], 
   Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1], Red]},
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 MaxRecursion -> 15]
```

[image]

```
FunctionDomain[ArcSin[(x^2 - 8)/8] - 2*ArcSin[x/4] + Pi/2, x]

(* -4 <= x <= 4 *)

Reduce[ArcSin[(x^2 - 8)/8] == 2*ArcSin[x/4] - Pi/2, x, Reals]

(* 0 <= x <= 4 *)
```

From the "Possible Issues" section of the documentation for [`FunctionDomain`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionDomain.html), "All subexpressions of f need to be real-valued for a point to belong to the real domain of f." Since the **subexpressions** are complex for `x > 4` the function domain (**as defined**) does not extend beyond `4`. Similarly, from the documentation for [`Reduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html), "If dom is Reals, or a subset such as Integers or Rationals, then all constants and function values are also restricted to be real." Again, since the function values for `x > 4` are not real, they are not included given the specified domain restriction. However, [`Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) correctly determines that the imaginary as well as the real parts cancel for `x > 4` resulting in `zero`.

```
Plot[ArcSin[(x^2 - 8)/8] - 2*ArcSin[x/4] + Pi/2, {x, -6, 6}, 
 PlotTheme -> "ThickLines",
 PlotRange -> All,
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 MaxRecursion -> 15,
 WorkingPrecision -> 15]
```

[image]

Comment: 1. According to traditional math, the real-valued function defined by `ArcSin[(x^2 - 8)/8] - 2*ArcSin[x/4] + Pi/2` is defined only for `x>=-4&&x<=4`. The domain of the difference/sum is the intersection of the domains of the terms. I see WRInc.'s math differs from  traditional math. 2. You wrote "Again, since the function values for `x > 4` are not real, they are not included given the specified domain restriction". Do you mean the result of `Reduce[ArcSin[(x^2 - 8)/8] == 2*ArcSin[x/4] - Pi/2, x, Reals]` is incorrect?

Comment: No, I mean that in accordance with the documentation, when restricted to `Reals` it does not consider any result with an intermediate result that is complex. The results above `4` are zero but `Reduce` essentially stops looking when you restrict the domain to `Reals` and it encounters a complex value.

Comment: The conclusion: WRInc.'s math differs from traditional math here, drawing the plot.

Comment: Just to compare. The command of Maple 2022 `plot(arcsin((x^2 - 8)/8) - 2*arcsin(x/4) + Pi/2, x = -6 .. 6)` draws the plot only on the interval $[-4,4]$.